# Sending Email after insertion of data using codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email

Sending email after inserting the data into database using `codeigniter` `PHP` is not working.Data is inserting succesfully but the `MAIL` functionality is not working getting as `www.hostname.com` page isn’t working.Can any one help me this.Thanks in advance.Here is my code.

**Controller:**

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
        { 
            parent::__construct();
            //here we will autoload the pagination library              
            $this->load->model('blogs_model');
            $this->load->library('email');
        }
        function addcomments()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name' , 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('location','Location');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description');
        if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
        {   
        $data['mainpage']='blogs';
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
        }
        else
        {

            //insert the user registration details into database
            $data=array(
                'blog_id'=>$this->input->post('bl_id'),
                'first_name'=>$this->input->post('first_name'),
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'description'=>$this->input->post('description'),
                'location'=>$this->input->post('location')
                );
            // insert form data into database
            if ($this->blogs_model -> insertcomments($data))
            {
                // send email
                if ($this->blogs_model->send_mail($this->input->post('email')))
                {
                    // successfully sent mail
                    $this->flash->success('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully Registered! Please confirm the mail sent to your Email-ID!!!</div>');
                    redirect("blog");
                }
                else
                {
                    // error
                    $this->flash->success('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                    redirect("blog");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // error
                $this->flash->success('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                redirect('blog');
            }
        }
        }
}
```

**Model:**

```
function insertcomments($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('comments', $data);
    //$this->db->insert('comments',$data);
    //return $this->input->post('bl_id');
}

function sendEmail($to_email)
{

    //configure email settings
    $config=Array(
    'protocol'=> 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com', //smtp host name
    'smtp_port' => '465', //smtp port number
    'smtp_user' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => '************', //$from_email password
    'mailtype' =>'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    //send mail
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->from('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Admin');
    $this->email->to('yyy@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Comments');
    $this->email->message('Testing');
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    return $this->email->send();
}
```

Comment: try this: `if($this->email->send())
{
echo "sent";
}
else
{
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}` will help u to find errors

Comment: @devpro getting the same error as The www.developer.domain.com page isn’t working

www.developer.domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: i think this is method name issue and u are using wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong method name for sending email in your controller:

```
$this->blogs_model->send_mail($this->input->post('email'))
```

Correct function name is `sendEmail()`

```
$this->blogs_model->sendEmail($this->input->post('email'))
```

Comment: @user7047368: glad to help u

Answer (score 0):

Check your code:

You should change function "**send_mail**" in your controller because in model you used "**sendEmail**".

Change in to your controller :

```
$this->blogs_model->sendEmail($this->input->post('email'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems in your code is this line
    `smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com`

try instead:  `smtp_host' => 'http://smtp.gmail.com`